# Get value select (Javascript) and Grid in Electronjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I don't know why the value in my div appears only one time ...

```
function nbProduct(sel) {
    var nbProduct = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text
    $('#tableFacture').remove();
    $('#tableFacture').remove();
    for(var i =0;i < nbProduct;i++){
        var nFacture = i + 1
        $("#product").append("<table id='tableFacture'></table>")
        $("#tableFacture").append("<th scope='row' id='rowProduct"+i+"'>Produit N°"+nFacture+"</th")
        $("#rowProduct"+i+"").append("<div class='row' syle='margin-top: 40px;' id='"+i+"'><select onChange='typeProduct(this);'><option></option><option value='"+i+"'>Velo</option><option value='"+i+"'>Trottinette</option><option value='"+i+"'>Accessoires</option></select></div>")
    }

function typeProduct(sel) {
    var typeOfProduct = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text
    var nbDiv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value
    if (typeOfProduct == 'Velo'){  
        $("#"+nbDiv+"").append("<div class='containerFacture><select id='factureVelo'><option></option></select></div>")
        client.query('SELECT * FROM core_velo ORDER BY model DESC',(err,res)=>{
        for(var i =0;i < res.rows.length;i++){
          var item = res.rows[i];
          var model = item['model']
        $("#factureVelo").append("<option>"+model+"</option>")
        }
    client.end()
        })
    }
};
```

[picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaAaf.png)

And I have an other problem, how use grid in electronjs ? because col-md/sm/XS ... do not work.

Comment: can you please provide what will be value of sel?

Comment: The value of my div

Comment: can you please provide me some example value or anything that you passing for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to try use:

```js
function typeProduct(sel) {
    var typeOfProduct = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text
    var nbDiv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value
    if (typeOfProduct == 'Velo'){  
        $("#"+nbDiv+"").append("<div class='containerFacture col-xs-2 offset-xs-1'><select          id='factureVelo'><option></option></select></div>")
        client.query('SELECT * FROM core_velo ORDER BY model DESC',(err,res)=>{
            var model ="";
            $.each(res, function(index, value){
                  model += value.model;
            })
            $("#factureVelo").append("<option>"+model+"</option>")
        }
    client.end()
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: You sure  object RES have value?